# too many open files azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am getting the following error while developing node js app to app service using azure-dev

```
  ##[error]Error: EMFILE: too many open files, open 'C:\agent\_work\_temp\temp_web_package_05489241004778522\node_modules\tar-fs\test\fixtures\d\file1'
```

I am deploying using windows hosted agent

Please find the task YAML file

```
steps:
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@3   displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: <>'   inputs:
    azureSubscription: <> 
    appType: api
    WebAppName: 'DEV-BIZ-API'
    DeployToSlotFlag: true
    ResourceGroupName: '<>'
    SlotName: temp
    GenerateWebConfig: true
    WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile app.js -appType node'
    AppSettings: '-NODE_ENV dev'
    ConfigurationSettings: '-NODE_ENV dev'
    TakeAppOfflineFlag: true
    UseWebDeploy: true
    RenameFilesFlag: true
```

Comment: can you post the tasks?

Comment: mean task YAML file

Answer (score 3):

> too many open files azure DevOps pipeline

There is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/4127) about this on Github.

> For windows, this issue is resolved with `2.117.1` agent version.

If your agent version is higher than `2.117.1`, but you still have this issue, you can try to the workaround:

- Provide the extracted package path as input for App Service Deploy
  task
- Use Post Deployment script feature to install app dependencies.

[image]

Note:You can also add your detailed info on the thread on the github, and check the feedback there.

Hope this helps.